# kafka message format for complex data\message

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

we are using kafka for stream processing in our system. The structure of the input data\message is very complex. so how to define the structure of the input message. which is the most suitable structure and serialization mechanism for the input data\message.

Comment: What is the Data source an how is the data structure defined in the source system?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below serializers to serialize your input messages.

1. [Apache commons lang3 serializer](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html) - easiest implementation
2. [Kryo Serialization](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) - fast and efficient serializer
3. [Avro Serialization](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/#intro) - supports schema evolution over time with registry

I would recommend you to implement the Kryo serailizer.